# Count by elements in a variable R

Tags: r, grouping, aggregate

I am attempting to count elements within a variable(column) and group it by elements in another variable.The table below is the current data I am working with:
                      `.                                     Company.Name        Sales.Team  Product.Family
1                                          example1    Global Accounts            FDS
2                                          example2           Americas            RDS
3                                          Example3            WEMEA 2       Research
4                                          Example4            WEMEA 2       Research
5                                          Example5                CEE       Research
6                                          Example6                CEE       Research`

What I am trying to do is is aggregate count of company names by different product families. So it would look something like:

```
                          FDS      RDS      Research   
Americas                    0        1             0
CEE                         0        0             2           
Global Accounts             1        0             0                   
WEMEA 2                     0        0             2
```

I have been messing around with the aggregate function, but this has not yielded the needed data. I am having trouble with determining how to have columns based on elements in a row.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `with(dat, table(Sales.Team, Product.Family))` or you could do `xtabs(~Sales.Team + Product.Family, data=dat)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this using the base table function in R. using an example table:
`table(example_table$Sales.Team, example_table$Product.Family)`

A basic run through for frequency tables can be found here at [quick-R](https://www.statmethods.net/stats/frequencies.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you need your output to be a dataframe, this is really easy using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

my_df <- data.frame("Product.Family" = c("FDS", "RDS", rep("Research", 4)), "Company.Name" = paste0("Example", 1:6), "Sales.Team" = c("Global Accounts", "Americas", rep("WEMA 2", 2), rep("CEE", 2)))

summary_df <- my_df %>% 
  group_by(Sales.Team) %>% 
  summarize(FDS = sum(Product.Family == "FDS"), RDS = sum(Product.Family == "RDS"), Research = sum(Product.Family == "Research"))
```